# Get resulting SQL from wordpress functions

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to do some inserting of posts but MySQL keeps dying. Solution is to actually run the insert/update queries manually through SQL than use wordpress. With this in mind, to save me rewriting huge chunks of logic, is there any way to dump the resulting SQL from the wp_insert_posts and other functions without actually running them?

I've tried the query save but it doesn't seem to save the insert queries. Ideally to a file but it'd be nice just to have a debug method to call to see the sql itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit wp-config.php and look for this line:

define('WP_DEBUG',false);

Change it to:
define('WP_DEBUG',true);

Then add this line right under it:
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG',true);

Run your offending command/operation and look for ./wp-content/debug.log.

That should give you more details on what is going wrong including the SQL error and some/all of the SQL command that caused the problem.

Make sure you turn off (set to false) both of those defines, ESPECIALLY if you do this on a live site.